# "Clean up" drupal mysql database after Drupal 6 » 7 upgrade

Tags: drupal-7

I recently upgraded my website from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7.  The number of tables in my MySQL database jumped from 135 tables to 283 tables. I may be wrong, but it seems to me that some of the tables are redundant copies left over from Drupal 6  (e.g., CCK fields now handled by Drupal 7 fields). Could/should I "clean up" the database by deleting the unused tables?  How would I know which ones are safe to delete?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should delete this tables if you know which ones are safe. )
Don't forget to make backup of your database.

Comment: How would I know which tables are safe? If I don't know... would there be any significant performance decrease from letting them just sit there?  I have a small site (around 500 nodes) on a shared server.

Comment: You may delete all tables with "content" prefix. No any performance decreasing will happen.

Answer (score -3):

I guess it is difficult to say which table belongs to which version of drupal. Make backup of your database and try to guess the tables to delete.